# Can we collapse noises by reducing temperature?

Tags: temperature, noise

Is it possible to reduce noises to any extent by decreasing temperature? please give answer using reference to article or website.

Comment: Some more context would be helpful. What sort noise are you thinking about here?

Comment: my question is overal. I have not speak about a certain noise.

Comment: If you cool the environment to 0 Kelvin the air will be frozen solid on the ground, so clearly no noise, But this is also likely not the kind of answer you care about: you need to give more context of what kind of situation we are talking about.

Comment: [Zero-point energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-point_energy): “Even at absolute zero, atoms and molecules retain some vibrational motion.”

Comment: cooling an amplifier is good to do: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_figure and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noise_temperature and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-noise_amplifier. The best are cryogenically cooled especially if you want to measure the CMB and some such

Comment: Just Google [noise temperature telescope](https://www.google.com/search?q=noise+temperature+telescope&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALiCzsaEkjeWZrvk4tfCxW7ij9vnYtX5sQ%3A1663971218335&ei=ki8uY9r7E-Wx8gKSq7qADA&ved=0ahUKEwjajIrr96v6AhXlmFwKHZKVDsAQ4dUDCA0&uact=5&oq=noise+temperature+telescope&gs_lcp=Cgxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAQAzIFCCEQoAEyBQghEKABOgoIABBHENYEELADOgQIABBHOgYIABAeEAc6BQgAEIAEOgYIABAeEBY6CAgAEB4QDxAWOgUIABCGAzoHCCEQoAEQCkoECEEYAEoECEYYAFCbE1ijeWCIpQFoBHAEeACAAcECiAGXC5IBBzcuNC4wLjGYAQCgAQHIAQjAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-serp)